# Blazor server hosted display alert if websockets not allowed

Tags: websocket, signalr, blazor-server-side

I would like to create a Blazor server hosted. Is there a way to display browser alert or redirect the user to another url, for example were Blazor Wasm is running, if SignalR cannot create a connection due to websockets not being allowed?

Can this be done using c# or Javascript?

Comment: You can do this with Javascript with logic like: Start the connection only allowing WebSocktes, if connectio start fails, then redirect.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know any Javascript, yout a suggestion where I can start from?

Comment: First of all start reading the JavaScript SignalR documentation by Microsoft. After that you will realize how to control the connection events and act when something occurs. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: @Kiril1512 Thank, if you can, please add an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yes, I will answer this and with a working code example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some Javascript implementing the following logic: Try to connect using Web Sockets, if fails, redirect.
Here is a my own working example in **TypeScript**:

```js
  public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .withUrl('http://localhost:20000/yourHub', signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
      .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));

        // do the redirect stuff here...
  }
}
```

If you not familiar with Javascript you can start read the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.0)  for Javascript client.